# Check if the request parameter equals a string in Java

Tags: java, request, query-string

I want to do this in java

```
if(request.getParameter("page") == "page1")
// page1
else if(request.getParameter("page") == "page2")
// page2
```

For someone new to java, why doesn't the above code work, and what is the best way to do what I want to do above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `String` is an object, not a primitive, the `==` would only compare them by reference, not by the object's internal representation. You need to compare them by [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

```
if("page1".equals(request.getParameter("page")))
// do something
else if("page2".equals(request.getParameter("page")))
// do something else
```

*(note, this style is done so to prevent potential `NullPointerException` on for example `request.getParameter("page").equals("page1")` when the parameter returns `null`)*

#### Related questions:

- [What is the difference between `==` and `equals()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505357/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-equals-with-hashcode)

---

Unrelated to the problem, the JSP is not the best place for this job. Consider a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Good point on the difference between the 2 styles.  I never thought about it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong equals.  Try this:

```
  if(request.getParameter("page") != null) {
    if(request.getParameter("page").equals("page1")) {
         // do stuff
    } else if(request.getParameter("page").equals("page2")) {
         // do other stuff
    }
  }
```

== compares the object references to see if they are equal, whereas .equals checks to see if the values of those object references are equal.