# Java: equals and ==

Tags: java, reference, equals

Lets see we have 2 references to instances of a user-defined class, a and b in Java.
Can there ever be a situation where
a == b but a.equals(b) return false?

Answer (score 8):

Sure! The implementation of `.equals()` is completely up to the class, so I could write:

```
class Foo
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't matter what two instances you pass — even the exact same instance twice — I'm always going to say they're not equal.

This particularly setup is silly, but it illustrates that you can get a `false` result from `.equals()` for the same object twice.

Note that we're talking here about what ***can*** happen, not what ***should***. No class should ever implement a `.equals` method that claims an object isn't equal to itself. For trusted code, it's reasonable to assume this will never happen.

Comment: However, it's _not_ possible if the `equals` contract is obeyed.

Comment: That's an important point; I've edited my answer to include that clarification. While technically possible, anyone who actually built such a thing deserves to have their programming license revoked.

Answer (score 5):

`if a == b` then `a.equals(b)` should be true. And if `a.equals(b)` then maybe `a == b` but not necessarily.

The `==` operator just test if both are referencing the same object. While `equals` executes a logic that you implemented. The last one can be overridden the first one is an operator from the language, and such as cannot be overridden in Java.

### References

[what is the difference between == operator and equals()? (with hashcode() ???)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505357/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-equals-with-hashcode)

From [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) documentation:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> 1. It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> 2. It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns
>      true.
> 3. It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then
>      x.equals(z) should return true.
> 4. It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or
>      consistently return false, provided no information used in equals
>      comparisons on the objects is modified.
> 5. For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just overload `equals` to do something silly.  e.g.

```
class Foo {
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object rhs) { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is obviously ***possible*** to write code that does this, as other answers have pointed out.

However, it is also ***always a logical error*** in the code, since it violates the implicit general contract of the equals() function.

An object should always be equal to itself, so if `(a==b)` then `a.equals(b)` ***should*** always return true.

Answer (score 2):

Ya we can overload the `.equals` function to give the desired output. but there is no case where `==` returns true while `.equals` returns false.

```
class s {
    int a;
}

class dev {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        s a = new s();
        s b = new s();
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }
}
```

```
Output
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily:

```
public class Wrong{
    public boolean equals(Object other) 
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, this completely breaks the normal rules for implementing `.equals()` - see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) - but there's nothing to stop you other than good sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method can be overridden in order to provide custom functionality other than the typical `==` method. Also, some types such as `Strings` will not return true when using the == method. You have to use `.equals` or `.compareTo` (equal when returns 0).

This should provide some [additional help](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stackOverFlow;

import java.util.Date;

public class SampleClass {

public static int  myint = 1;
private SampleClass() {
};

public Integer returnRandom() {
    return myint++;
}

private static SampleClass _sampleClass;

public static SampleClass getInstance() {

    if (_sampleClass == null) {
        _sampleClass = new SampleClass();
    }
    return _sampleClass;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this.returnRandom().equals(((SampleClass) other).returnRandom())) {
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

}



package com.stackOverFlow;

public class Run {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SampleClass a = SampleClass.getInstance();
    SampleClass b = SampleClass.getInstance();
    if(a==b){
        System.out.println("references are same as they are pointing to same object");
        if(!a.equals(b)){
            System.out.println("two random number Instance will never be same");
        }
    }

}

}
```

You can understand this by Practical example. where a singeleton class will always return you same reference, and you can override equals method to get something that is not class variable. example a value from database at two particular time , or a random number. Hope that clears your case

Comment: This is just a wall of poorly-formatted code and as it is currently written it needs at least two reads for someone who already knows Java to understand.

Comment: @Joey I am new to SO, will take care next time. thanks for pointing that out