# Java: Comparing [All] Instance Variables of an Object

Tags: java

I've a little problem.

Myself and a few friends were playing poker yesterday but we didn't have chips so I decided to start writing a program for that [Without Cards, just Chips].

In my code I have two main variables in the *Game Object*.

```
private int id;
private long bank;
```

I have a different file called *Aside* in which I can do different calculations.

In the code below I am trying to compare all instance *bank* variables to see if all the banks matched [In this case this will mean a new card can be drawn, otherwise users will have to keep to either raise or fold].

Is there a way of writing this in an easier term:

```
package poker;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aside
{

    public boolean compareBanks(ArrayList<Game> x)
    {
        ArrayList<Game> players = new ArrayList(x);

        if(players.get(0).getBank() == players.get(1).getBank() && players.get(0).getBank() == players.get(2).getBank() 
            && players.get(1).getBank() == players.get(2).getBank())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Later I use this here:

```
while(aside.compareBanks(players))
```

But the loop keeps going.

I'm fairly intermediate in programming so go easy on me with mistakes.

Thank you for your time.

P.S: This is NOT a code dump.

```
while(aside.compareBanks(players))
        {

            for(Game x : players)
            {
                if(x.hasPayedBid() == true)
                    {

                    System.out.println("Player : " + x.getName() +  " [Call, Raise, Fold]:");
                    action = in.nextLine();
                    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("call"))
                    {
                      break;
                    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("raise"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("How much are you raising? $");
                        int raise = in.nextInt();

                        table += raise;

                        x.raise(raise);
                    }else
                    {
                        x.fold();
                    }
                }
            }

            in.nextLine();

            for(Game x : players)
            {
                System.out.println(x.toString() + "\n");
            }

        }//End While
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: equals and ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378309/java-equals-and)

Comment: compare objects qith `.eqials()` method (which you'll have to implement)  instead of `==`

Comment: Bank is a long not a string though. I believe you can't use *.equals()* on a long.

Comment: Do you change the bank values inside your loop ?

Comment: Yeah. I'll post the code for the while loop now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `java-8 Stream API` something like this

return  players.stream().allMatch(p ->  p.getBlank().equals( players.get(0).getBalnk()))

However if you will use `while(aside.compareBanks(players))` and all elements of the list have equal `blank` value, your while loop will never stop. It is the same as `while(true)`. So in this case you probably need to use `if(aside.compareBanks(players))` or in case of equal blank values change them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
long bankValue=0;
For(Game player: players){
```

bankValue+=player.getBank();
}

```
if(bankValue==(players.get(0).getBank()*players.size)){
```

return true;}

```
else return false;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does the if statement do. The logic for me looks a bit tangled.

Comment: We are validating the sum of all players bank is equal to the number players multiply first player bank value.

Comment: Oh. Okay that sounds interesting. Does the code handle with the case of: 

Player 1 Bank: $47
Player 1 Bank: $53
Player 1 Bank: $50

That sum still ends up being: $150