# Comparing two objects in Java

Tags: java

I have two different objects of same entity “Community”

And two objects(community and com) have same values

Communty.java have following variables:

```
   private Integer communityId;
   private String communityName;
   private String description;

   // many to many relationship
   private Set<Faculty> faculties = new HashSet<Faculty>();
   private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

and I used equal method as:

```
@Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(obj==null)
                 return false;
          if(obj==this)
                 return true;
          if(!(obj instanceof Community)) return false;

          Community community = (Community)obj;
          return community.getCommunityId() == this.getCommunityId();
   }
```

When I checked `community==com` , it returns false .. why? What mistake I have done? Both the objects are retrieved from the database!

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between == operator and equals()? (with hashcode() ???)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505357/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-equals-with-hashcode)

Comment: whether u had overrided public int hashCode()

Comment: no.. i have not overrided hashCode() but using equals() in the return statment of the equals() defined above worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` compares links to the objects.

You should explicitly call `community.equals(com)`. Also take care of the *null* checks.

Comment: it still says false after using community.equals(com) and community.getCommunityId() and com.getCommunityId are same!

Comment: you should check my answer for the possible reason

Comment: Try to change your last statement in your `equals` method to `return this.getCommunityId().equals(community.getCommunityId());`

As stated in other answer, `Integer`s, unlike `int`s also require `equals` method to be compared correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're comparing objects (the IDs) using `==` rather than `equals()`. `==` tests if both variables reference the same object. `equals()` tests if the two variables reference two functionally equal integers (i.e. with the same int value).

It's almost always a bug to compare objects using `==`, except for enums.

Answer (score 2):

`==` compares the two references which may be pointing to two different locations irrespective of the object content.

You should use `community.equals(com)` to check for equality'

Also, your equals method contains the following segment :

```
community.getCommunityId() == this.getCommunityId()
```

as `communityId` is an `Integer` object, the `==` operator may give negative result for integer values which are not in the range [-127, 128] due to interning, thats a separate concept, you can check it later.

You need to use `equals()` there as well or compare the .`intValue()`

```
return community.getCommunityId().equals(this.getCommunityId())
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, they don't refer same object. `==` used to check, whether both referring same object.

`==` for object refer to same.

`equals` content equivalency.

try this

```
return community.getCommunityId().equals(this.getCommunityId());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your equals method is that you are using `==` operator for Objects. And here the CommunityId must be the same object in order to return true:

```
 return community.getCommunityId() == this.getCommunityId();
```

It should be

```
 return community.getCommunityId().equals(this.getCommunityId());
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I checked community==com , it returns false .. why

This means; are these two *references* exactly the same. i.e. to the same object.  What you intended was

```
boolean equal = community.equals(com);
```

BTW Your `if (obj == null)` check is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

== operator in Java compares the memory address of the two objects,in your case comm and community must be two different objects stored at two different memory addresses

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two distinct objects communityId's.
is it necessary to declare communityId as Integer? because Integer is an object.
Why don't you simply declare communityId with a primitive type int;
int communityId should work.