# Unable To Meet MAC Address Condition Check - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, string, boolean

I'm attempting to check to ensure the device has a MAC address set using java - however I'm having trouble implementing the check to do so. I've attempted to use the following:

```
if (MAC == "00:00:00:00:00:00"){


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain.this);
                builder.setMessage("You Have No MAC Address!")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //do things
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
```

However the condition is never met - even with the value of MAC set to 00:00:00:00:00:00.

I thought this might be the way I am comparing to the two values. So then I tried this:

```
if (MAC = "00:00:00:00:00:00"){


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain.this);
                builder.setMessage("You Have No MAC Address!")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //do things
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
```

But I end up with the error: Type mismatch cannot convert from a String to a Boolean.

My question is: What would be the best method of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Never compare strings with ==.  Use .equals() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use equals() method and check, you will get proper results.

Visit [what is the difference between == operator and equals()? (with hashcode() ???)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505357/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-equals-with-hashcode) to understand fully the difference.