# Compact equals and hashcode

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a bean with 4 attributes:

```
user
institutionId
groupId
postingDate
```

I use Eclipse to generate equals and hashcode but the resulting code is not pretty. Is there a compact way to do the same? Assuming I want equals & hashcode to use all the attributes or a subset of them.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((groupId == null) ? 0 : groupId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((institutionId == null) ? 0 : institutionId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((postingDate == null) ? 0 : postingDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ManGroupKey other = (ManGroupKey) obj;
    if (groupId == null) {
        if (other.groupId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!groupId.equals(other.groupId))
        return false;
    if (institutionId == null) {
        if (other.institutionId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!institutionId.equals(other.institutionId))
        return false;
    if (postingDate == null) {
        if (other.postingDate != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!postingDate.equals(other.postingDate))
        return false;
    if (user == null) {
        if (other.user != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!user.equals(other.user))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "compact way"? It depends on what your requirements for `equals` is. If you don't need it all, delete some. IIRC there are some reflective ones as well, alternate generators, and ways to choose which fields are used.

Comment: Sonar reports a lot of  "If Stmts Must Use Braces" warnings. Hashcode is fine, equals is very difficult to read.

Comment: @LluisMartinez Reformat it.

Comment: Take a look at `Objects.equals` and `Objects.hash` in `java.util` for Java >= 7, otherwise google guava has those helpers.

Comment: I'm stuck with Java 5 and can't use Guava, but that's the way I'd like.

Comment: The implementation provided by netbeans is correct if you consider that you object is an entity identificable by those instance attributes. You could als take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java, for further theoretical background on this matter, but for a pragmatic point of view this is just correct.

Comment: I usually remove the auto-generated `null` checks, when I'm sure that my class permits no `null` values for the attributes in question (e.g. by checking in constructor and having immutable properties). This saves a considerable amount of generated code.

Comment: Guava _does_ have a Java 5 backport...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the eclipse generated code, you can use Apache-common-langs(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) class  HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder  to do this:

```
public int hashCode() {
   return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}


public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this);
 }
```

Comment: Although there are some possible drawbacks: 1. reflection is slower, 2. the order is not really under your control, 3. all fields are used (which might or might not be what you want)

Comment: I pick this one because: a) I can't use Java 7 (or Guava) b) performance is not an issue (not thousands of objects) and c) in this case I use all fields.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 7

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(groupId, institutionId, postingDate, user);
}
```

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    // cast to correct class
    Target o = (Target)obj;

    return Objects.equals(groupId, o.groupId) &&
           Objects.equals(institutionId, o.institutionId) &&
           Objects.equals(postingDate, o.postingDate) &&
           Objects.equals(user, o.user);
}
```

Comment: You need to cast obj in the equals method.

Answer (score 5):

You could compact the code down, but the odds are far higher that you would introduce bugs than that you would do anything useful. All the parts of the equals and hash code method are there for a reason.

If it's bothering you most IDEs have a folding editor, just click the little yellow box (usually) and all the contents of the method get hidden away.

Answer (score 2):

hashCode:
 Either:

```
@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(user, institutionId, groupId, postingDate);
}
```

Or:

```
@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(user);
    result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(institutionId);
    result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(groupId);
    result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(postingDate);
    return result;
}
```

Equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj == this){
        return true;
    }
    if (! (obj instanceof ManGroupKey)){
        return false;
    }
    ManGroupKey other = (ManGroupKey) obj;
    return Objects.equals(user, other.user)
           && Objects.equals(institutionId, other.institutionId)
           && Objects.equals(groupId, other.groupId)
           && Objects.equals(postingDate, other.postingDate);
}
```

Comment: return Objects.equals(user, other.user). I cannot edit myself, since 6 characters must be changed, "user " got just four :)

Answer (score 1):

You can at least remove one level of nesting by removing the `other.x != null` check.

Comparing a value in this way: `x.equals(y)` will always return `false` when `y` is `null`.

Aside from that: the `.equals()` method is a good example where a bit of reflection can be handy, possible extracted out into a generic utility method. All you have to do is run through the different fields and see if they're equal in the two objects, that can be done in a few lines.

Obviously that is only feasible when you actually want to compare each field (or you'll have to add some additions to it which let you choose the fields).

Comment: But then you won't return true if both self and other have x as null.

Comment: @TimB: if you invert the checks and instead use `if(this.postingDate != null) { if(!(this.postingData.equals(other.postingData))}` then this should not be a problem, right? Just return `false` for every intermediate check and return `true` at the very end as fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I think the library, that can suite you is apache common. It provides `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder` classes, that do exactly what you are looking for.

Consider this question for details: [Apache Commons equals/hashCode builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038204/apache-commons-equals-hashcode-builder)

Here are some code snippets:

```
public class Bean{

    private String name;
    private int length;
    private List<Bean> children;


    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(name)
            .append(length)
            .append(children)
            .toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Bean){
            final Bean other = (Bean) obj;
            return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(name, other.name)
                .append(length, other.length)
                .append(children, other.children)
                .isEquals();
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```