# Perfect hashing function and benefits

Tags: java, hash

Consider this class :

```
    public final class MyDate {
        private int year, month, day;

        public MyDate(int year, int month, int day) {
             this.year = year;
             this.month = month;
             this.day = day;
        }

        //Some stuff

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
             return ((year << 4) | month) << 5 | day;
        }
}
```

This is a perfect hashing function because in the memory we have :

[image]

So in red, `5 bits` store the day (1 to 31), in yellow `4 bits` store the month (1 to 12) and the others store the year (1 to 16777215).

What's the benefit of a perfect `hashFunction` ? AFAIK, it can guaranted the add/remove/contains in `O(1)` in an `HashSet` but could I get other benefits of having one ?

I saw that many hash functions use prime numbers, what's the best manner to construct one (I imagine that create a perfect hashfunction is uncommun/rare) ?

---

**EDIT :**

About prime numbers -> answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode)

Comment: your perfect hash function is only useful if the underlying hash array is sized to fit all possible values (which is unlikely with a jdk HashSet/HashMap).

Comment: I don't get it: why put a date in a hashset when I can easily create a new instance when I need one?

Comment: @Andy That's an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A perfect hash function guarantees that you'll have no collisions. However, in order to be able to use one, you have to know exactly the set of key values that will need to be hashed, which is often not the case.

Others not so perfect, but still good hash functions (along with a collision resolution mechanism) don't have that requirement and are very fast to compute anyway, so they are often more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As per Juampi it's fast.
How fast? 
Approximately O(1). 
Redis is a great example of constant time lookups in memory through hash table.

If you do not have a bucket of exactly one element on the results of the hash you then need to use equals to compare each item so you get lookup of O(1 plus z) where z is the bucket size.

But yes very slow hash functions certainly aren't a great idea after.