# Override hashCode-method in Java: Why does it work?

Tags: java, overriding, primes, hashcode

I have overwritten the hashcode-method for my class (with one instance variable named "id").

```
public int hashCode()
{
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;

  result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

What exactly happens in the last line? There should be two different cases:

Case 1: id == null , which means that result should be equal to 31.

Case 2: id != null , which means that result should be equal to 31 + id.hashCode();

I do not understand the two cases (or i am not even sure if they are correct). And what is the point of the prime number anyway? Why should we assign the null reference to 31?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=hashcode+in+java+joshua&source=bl&ots=yYLjPnpZU_&sig=lDXdsiTqmnu_TU3PO81E3S7rQ1E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k9YiU9raJsPrrQfVz4DgAw&ved=0CHEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=hashcode%20in%20java%20joshua&f=false Best place from where you can learn about hashcode and why 31 only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the point of the prime number anyway? 
>   31 is a ODD-PRIME number and to choose an Odd number prevents multiplication over-flow and prime is a traditional approach.

I think this part can be understand in more detailed manner from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode)

> Why should we assign the null reference to 31

`((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode())`
Here we are checking if id has a non-null value or not. If there is some non-null value then it must be having some hashcode and we are adding that hashcode in our object's hashcode.
So this way your hashcode for `two object will differ if id for those two object differs`.

Comment: but why do i need 31? i've read everything but i don't get it. Couldn't i just use id.hashCode(); why do i multiply with 31? If the hashcode of id is unique it would be still unique if we mulitply it with a number, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you remove multiplication by 31 then also hashcode will be unique. but for efficiency we need to multiply it by odd prime.

Comment: so why is it more efficient?

Comment: This is what i have directly picked from the source u suggested ub comment "The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. "...