# Is this a good implementation of hashCode()?

Tags: java, equals, implementation, hashcode

I have a `class` that will be used in a `HashSet`. It only contains two members, and both are of the same type interface. This is what it looks like:

```
class MyClass{
    MyInterface a;
    MyInterface b;

    public int hashCode(){
         return a.hashCode() + b.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
         if(!(obj instanceof MyClass)
              return false;
         MyClass other (MyClass) obj;
         return (this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b) || (this.a == other.b && this.b == other.a);
    }
}
```

As you can see, two instances of `MyClass` are "equal" if they contain the same two instances of `MyInterface`.

Now, I was thinking that for `hashCode()`, I could just add up the default hashcodes of its members. Is this good enough? If not, what is a proper implementation of `hashCode()` for this case?

Comment: how is a and b's hashcode defined ?

Comment: This will provide an unequal hashcode distribution: elements around `Integer.MaxValue / 2` will be disproportionally represented compared to those at the extremes, leading to more hash collisions.

Comment: Xor might be a better option than addition. Shouldn't have the uneven distribution problem that @JeroenVannevel mentioned.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I don't believe that's true.  If the hash codes of the elements are uniformly distributed, then for overflow reasons the hash codes of the sums of the hash codes will be uniformly distributed.

Comment: You could also use: `return Objects.hash(a, b);`

Comment: @assylias no, that would give two different hashcodes for equal objects, because [a, b] is equal to [b, a]

Comment: @assylias the OP appears to require something order-agnostic which `Objects.hash` is not

Comment: @LouisWasserman: good point, I disregarded overflowing.

Comment: I believe what you're using is also the default `hashCode()` function supplied by certain IDE's such as eclipse. (Suggesting that while you could probably do better with a specially designed hash function, this one is a decent lazy/backup option.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3613764/99248 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3613423/99248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine.  It's equivalent to the implementation of `Set.hashCode()` for two-element sets.

Comment: @River: Like I commented elsewhere, assuming `a.hashCode()` and `b.hashCode()` have proper hash code implementations that offer proper value distribution to begin with, I really don't see how the extra calculation will help reduce the likelihood of collisions.  OP's implementation is fine.

Comment: That being said, you could almost certainly do better (less-collisions) with a finer-tuned hash function. The real question is whether it's worth your time to optimize this function rather than simply stick with one that is "good enough".

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. Wouldn't this mean that these two instances of `MyClass` would hash to the same value:

```
MyClass {
  a.hashCode = 2;
  b.hashCode = 3;
}
```

and

```
MyClass {
  a.hashCode = 1;
  b.hashCode = 4;
}
```

Comment: So you have a hash collision.  So what?  Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: This is bound to happen... Perfect hash functions are near impossible

Comment: Maybe my example is overly simplistic, but it seems like a more complete implementation could minimize the number of collision. Do I have a better suggestion? No.

Comment: You could do a combination of + and *, which are both associative and commutative (which are required): `(a.hashCode() + b.hashCode()) * 31 + (a.hashCode() * b.hashCode())`.

Comment: @Clashsoft: Assuming `a.hashCode()` and `b.hashCode()` have proper hashcode implementations that offer proper value distribution to begin with, I don't see any compelling reason to complicate the calculation.

Comment: I know, I wouldn't do that either if the hashCode of the two objects is reasonably well-distributed. This was just a response to the case represented by @DanForbes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Because even with hashCode collision, [the docs state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.