# Use a specific object-property to index, using a Map structure

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, graph

I'd like to use the integer-id-value of my vertex-class as an index, in my Map-structure, without using a parallel data structure.

```
class Vertex {
    private int v;
    private int label;

    //...
}
```

I store vertex objects, in a `Map<Vertex,ArrayList<Edge>> adjMap`.

Is it possible use the v-property of my Vertex class, as an index-key in my Map?

Comment: is your `integer-id-value` unique?

Comment: @karthik, yes it is.

Comment: You mean Map key should work on based on v property of Vertex?

Comment: @TheCodingFrog, yes indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Then your `equals` and `hashcode` should only use property v. Code below:

```
public class Vertex {

    private int v;
    private int label;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Vertex, String> map = new HashMap<Vertex, String>();

    Vertex vertex = new Vertex();
    vertex.v = 5;
    vertex.label = 10; 

    map.put(vertex, "vertex");

    Vertex vertex2 = new Vertex();
    vertex2.v = 5;
    vertex2.label = 100;  

    System.out.println("Value:: "+ map.get(vertex2));
}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + v;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
        if (v != other.v)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Output: Value:: vertex

Comment: when `v` is unique, you don't have to do any extra calculations to calculate `hasCode`. Just returning `v` would do.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode

Comment: You use prime number to avoid collisions in generating `hasCode`.

Comment: Ok so you know the answer to your own question.

Comment: Your `hashCode` method is equivalent to `return 31+v;`. Since you are not multiplying any member of the Vertex class by 31, it makes no difference and you might as well just `return v;`.

Comment: Good point Eran! Understood and thanks to both of you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Map implementation you are using. For example, for a HashMap you can override `equals` and `hashCode` of your `Vertex` class so that two vertices will be considered equal if their v properties are equal.

```
class Vertex {
    private int v;
    private int label;

    public Vertex (int v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o)
    {
        if (!(o instanceof Vertex))
            return false;
        Vertex ov = (Vertex)o;
        return this.v == ov.v;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now, to locate the value for a given v value in your Map :

```
adjMap.containKey(new Vertex(v));
```