# Hashing a key by folding then dividing by a prime number?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashcode, hash-function

I want to hash the following key  "LOWELL" using a simple hash function that used 3 steps  :

Step 1: transform the key into a number.

```
LOWELL = | L | O | W | E | L | L | | | | | | |
ASCII code: 76 79 87 69 76 76 32 32 32 32 32 32
```

> my question here why it added more 6 empty positions with fixed ASCII code 32

Step 2: fold and add (chop off pieces of the number and add
them together)

```
7679|8769|7676|3232|3232|3232|
7679+8769+7676+3232+3232+3232 = 33,820
```

Step 3: take the mod by a prime number

33,820 mod 19937 = 13,883

> Another question here for why dividing by prime numbers i found this
>   answer : Dividing by a number is good when there are sequences of
>   consecutive numbers. If there are many dierent sequences of
>   consecutive numbers, dividing by a number that has many small factors
>   may result in lots of collisions. A prime number is a better choice. but i didn't get it

Step 4: divide by the size of the address space (preferably a prime number). 13,883 mod 101 = 46

> finally why it divided the address space ?!

You can find detailed steps [here](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~bkurt/Courses/blg341/lecture13_6_slides_per_page.pdf)  (Slide 350)
Many Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Note: `WELOLL      ` will give exactly the same value ... and `WOLELL   ` ... and ...

Answer (score 1):

Since your address space contains only `101` slots, you cannot put your record in a position whose address exceeds this limit.

So you take the reminder of division of the output from the hash function (`13,883` in your case) by the address space, to make sure that the location of the record falls in the allowed address space.

So `h(s) % address_space` will always give allowed position within your address space.

Regarding your first question, why do we use a prime number in hashing, this thread will help you:
[Why use a prime number in hashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode)