# Iteration In Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

For example:

```
Public Class SomeClass{
      private String value1;
private String value2;
private String value3;
private Double value4;
//getters & setters of above
}
```

Consider the input `ArrayList` of `Object`(SomeClass):
    Object has variables of type `String,String,String` and `double`

```
`List<SomeClass> inputList = [{a,b,c,32.14},{d,e,f,47.50},{g,h,i,60.23}{j,k,l,47.69},{d,e,f,15.56},{a,b,c,25.41}];`
```

Consider 2 objects in inputList : `{a,b,c,32.14},{a,b,c,25.41}`

If variables of object {a,b,c,32.14} `String,String,String`.equals(String,String,String) of other objects `{a,b,c,25.41}` just sum their double value and convert it into single object `{a,b,c,57.55}`.

As a result of above I would like to have result in some ArrayList of object:

```
List<SomeClass> outputList = [{a,b,c,57.55},{d,e,f,62.66},{g,h,i,60.23},{j,k,l,47.69}];
```

Please let me know the logic to implement the above scenario?**Nested for loop will be fine**

Comment: you could override the `equals` and `hashCode` variable in order to notice pretty easily what is equal. Further on just compare the whole `List` against each other and sum up..

Comment: Could you provide us with code you have already written yourself that shows what you have tried so far?

Comment: @KevinEsche I have edited some changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hashMap and check if this key already exists then update the double value by adding existing double value then put in the map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    list.add(new MyObject("a","b","c",new BigDecimal(10.23)));
    list.add(new MyObject("a","b","e",new BigDecimal(10.23)));
    list.add(new MyObject("a","b","c",new BigDecimal(10.23)));
    list.add(new MyObject("a","b","d",new BigDecimal(10.23)));
    Map<MyObject,MyObject> map = new HashMap<MyObject,MyObject>(){
       @Override
    public MyObject put(MyObject key, MyObject value) {
           //synchronize if required
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            value.addDouble(get(key).myDouble);
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
    };

 for (MyObject obj:list) {
        map.put(obj, obj);
    }
    for (MyObject obj : map.values())
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Output:

```
abd10.230000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875
abc20.460000000000000852651282912120223045349121093750
abe10.230000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875
```

Make sure to use hashCode and equals only on first 3 properties. Not on double.

```
class MyObject {
    String myProp1;
    String myProp2;
    String myProb3;
    BigDecimal myDouble;

    public MyObject(String myProp1, String myProp2, String myProb3, BigDecimal myDouble) {
        super();
        this.myProp1 = myProp1;
        this.myProp2 = myProp2;
        this.myProb3 = myProb3;
        this.myDouble = myDouble;
    }
    public void addDouble(BigDecimal addValue) {
        myDouble = myDouble.add(addValue);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = PRIME * result + ((myProb3 == null) ? 0 : myProb3.hashCode());
        result = PRIME * result + ((myProp1 == null) ? 0 : myProp1.hashCode());
        result = PRIME * result + ((myProp2 == null) ? 0 : myProp2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
        if (myProb3 == null) {
            if (other.myProb3 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!myProb3.equals(other.myProb3))
            return false;
        if (myProp1 == null) {
            if (other.myProp1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!myProp1.equals(other.myProp1))
            return false;
        if (myProp2 == null) {
            if (other.myProp2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!myProp2.equals(other.myProp2))
            return false;
          return true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: The equals and hashCode method can be simplified using `java.util.Objects` class. Look at my answer or code here https://www.codiva.io/p/cb3a388d-41dd-43b6-8ee6-1dd7f5f1df19

Comment: @Gaurava Agarwal what is the int PRIME initalized in hashcode method?and why 31?

Comment: Please see this post for explanation on PRIME: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode

Comment: @Gaurava Agarwal List<MyObject> **list** = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); where did you use **list** in the new HashMap ?

Comment: @sundaresan.c, I have added required code and output as well. Please vote up if it is helpful.

Comment: Your code almost works .myDouble not getting added. Its showing input value itself. In output I am not getting summed value of mydouble. why did you use bigdecimal instead of double? @GauravaAgarwal .

Comment: Moreover I am using class variables with getters & setters for each parameters. Does the usage of constructor really necessary here? @GauravaAgarwal

Comment: You can check answer of both questions at stack overflow itself. I have shown you output of this code as is. See combination abc has updated Double value in map. Can you upload your code

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal .  I have used SomeClass as :      

Public Class SomeClass{
      private String value1;
private String value2;
private String value3;
private Double value4;
//with getters & setters of above

}

Note: **I can't use constructors here**

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal . please suggest addDouble method in your answer for input parameter with double as datatype

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal . Thanks . Its working . I have slightly modified addDouble method.

Answer (score 1):

First, define the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Advise: Don't reimplement the wheel. Just use java.util.Objects class' `equals` and `hash` methods. That reduces a large number of errors.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null)
  {
     return false;
  }
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
  {
     return false;
  }
  final SomeClass other = (SomeClass) obj;

  return   Objects.equals(this.value1, other.value1)
        && Objects.equals(this.value2, other.value2)
        && Objects.equals(this.value3, other.value3);
```

}

For the combiner, use the Java 8's `groupingBy` method that groups by the key (which is identity in this case) and the you can define the value to be summing of the value4 field.

```
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new SomeClass("a", "b", "c", 12.4));
list.add(new SomeClass("a", "b", "c", 31.4));
list.add(new SomeClass("c", "b", "c", 12.4));
list.add(new SomeClass("d", "b", "c", 12.4));


Function<SomeClass,SomeClass> identity = Function.identity();
Map<SomeClass, Double> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(identity,
        Collectors.summingDouble(SomeClass::getValue4)));

List<SomeClass> result = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
         e -> new SomeClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))).values());
System.out.println(result);
```

The full code in [Codiva online java complier IDE](https://www.codiva.io/p/cb3a388d-41dd-43b6-8ee6-1dd7f5f1df19).

Comment: JackDaniels I am using java 7. Suggest the combiner method for the same

Comment: Are you okay using Google Guava library?  It has a lot of useful features, that would make it simpler

Comment: https://www.codiva.io/p/825fd968-13e0-4dbc-a382-03aa13b96ebd has the java7 version using guava library

Answer (score -1):

Implement hashCode and equals methods in your object and try to add object in set it will provide you desire output.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    MyObject newObj = (MyObject)obj;

    if (newObj.getA().equals(this.getA()) && newObj.getB().equals(this.getB()) && newObj.getC().equals(this.getC())){
        newObj.setDoubleValue(this.getDoubleValue()+newObj.getDoubleValue());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: equals and hashcode need lot of improvements. You can see generated hashCode equals from IDE. To this particular question, its important to not use DoubleValue.

Comment: That was sample code.. did not mean to use it directly

Comment: Everyone should take care what they are referring. And thanks for your suggestions **will keep that in mind**